# jquery .val for textarea turns up blank

Tags: jquery, html

This is my first post ... so here it goes!

I'm trying to get the value of a text area upon a button click - one of 2 -> it registers the button clicks and triggers my php script fine but won't register the textarea contents, it shows up as empty. I've used .val, .text and .html. I'm not sure what's wrong ...

HTML:

```
<div> <textarea id="comments_box" placeholder="Reasoning for your decision ..." style="width:99%" ></textarea> </div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#reject").click(function(){
        var comments = $("#comments_box").val();
                    alert(comments);
 });



$("#accept").click(function(){
        var comments = $("#comments_box").val();
                    alert(comments);
 });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.val;` use `.val();` that will fix your problem. Please, it's also important  that you constantly check the browser console for javascript syntax errors.

---

Just to add something, if your textarea is in DOM, please use the following:

```
$('#reject').on('click', function(){ /*your code*/ });
```

Comment: it wasn't showing up as an error in the console ... but thank you!

Comment: @user1527634 did your textarea generated from DOM? try using $("#reject").on('click', function(){ //your code });

Comment: @user1527634 No problem, I am here to help :]

Answer (score 7):

You forgot the `()` after `val`. Should be `var comments = $("#comments_box").val();`.

Comment: ... I can't believe I forgot the parens ... thanks! ... But it still doesn't show up - it alerts as an empty string - any other ideas?

Comment: Did you type something into the textarea? The placeholder will not show up.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#reject").click(function(){
        var comments = $("#comments_box").val;
                    alert(comments);

$("#accept").click(function(){
        var comments = $("#comments_box").val;
                    alert(comments);
```

Needs to be...

```
$("#reject").click(function(){
        var comments = $("#comments_box").val();
        alert(comments);
});
$("#accept").click(function(){
        var comments = $("#comments_box").val();
        alert(comments);
});
```

Comment: No. You don't wanna print the function.

Comment: @Nullpo When I wrote that I hadn't noticed that part.  I was focusing on the lack of closing `});` at the end of both click registrations.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Oh, I had more code so I didn't add the closing parens when I copied pasta ... sorry!